Integration test with XUnit, Mocking inner Http Request when using API call end to end test
i have a class that holds HttpClient that posts a request:
public class PaPdfApiService : IPaPdfApiService
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
    private readonly ILogger<PaPdfApiService> _logger;


    public PaPdfApiService(HttpClient httpClient, ILogger<PaPdfApiService> logger)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    
    public async Task<string> GetDataAsync(string endpoint)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(endpoint);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }

    public async Task<string> PostDataAsync<TRequest>(string endpoint, TRequest requestData)
    {
        string content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestData, new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            DateFormatString = "yyyy-MM-dd",
            Formatting = Formatting.Indented,
            ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
        });
        byte[] buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(content);
        HttpContent httpContent = new ByteArrayContent(buffer);
        httpContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue(MediaTypeNames.Application.Json);

        HttpRequestMessage message = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, endpoint);
        message.Content = httpContent;

        _logger.LogInformation("PostDataAsync for endpoint : {endpoint}, content: {@content}", endpoint, content);
        HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await _httpClient.SendAsync(message);

        // Check for success status code
        if (responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            // Read the response content
            string responseContent = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            _logger.LogInformation("PostDataAsync was success with response : {responseContent}", responseContent);

            return responseContent;
        }
        else
        {
            _logger.LogError("PostDataAsync had failed with response status: {StatusCode}, body: {@body}", responseMessage.StatusCode, responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());

            // Handle error
            throw new HttpRequestException($"Error: {responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()}");
        }
    }
}

I want to replace this call :
HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await _httpClient.SendAsync(message);

in my integration test - to prevent the outer source from being tested.
code startup contains this setup :
services.AddHttpClient<IPaPdfApiService, PaPdfApiService>(client =>
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(pdfGeneratorSettings.BaseAddress);
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization =
        new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic",
            Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"{pdfGeneratorSettings.UserName}:{pdfGeneratorSettings.Password}")));
})
.ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() =>
{
    var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
    handler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (message, cert, chain, errors) => true;
    return handler;
});

I was trying to mock the call response to return an arranged result from my test class:
public class PersonalAgreementModuleTests : IClassFixture<CustomWebApplicationFactory<Startup>>
{
    private readonly AuthenticationModuleTests _authModuleTests;
    private readonly HttpClient _client;
    private readonly CustomWebApplicationFactory<Startup> _factory;

    public PersonalAgreementModuleTests(CustomWebApplicationFactory<Startup> factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
        
        _authModuleTests = new AuthenticationModuleTests(factory);

        _factory.WithWebHostBuilder(builder =>
        {
            builder.ConfigureServices(services =>
            {
                // Remove the existing HttpClient and PaPdfApiService registration
                var serviceDescriptor = services.FirstOrDefault(d => d.ServiceType == typeof(IPaPdfApiService));
                if (serviceDescriptor != null)
                {
                    services.Remove(serviceDescriptor);
                }

                // Mock HttpMessageHandler
                var mockHttpHandler = new Mock<HttpMessageHandler>();
                mockHttpHandler.Protected()
                    .Setup<Task<HttpResponseMessage>>(
                        "SendAsync",
                        ItExpr.Is<HttpRequestMessage>(req =>
                            req.Method == HttpMethod.Post), // Match specific endpoint
                        ItExpr.IsAny<CancellationToken>())
                    .ReturnsAsync(new HttpResponseMessage
                    {
                        StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK,
                        Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject("5555"), Encoding.UTF8, MediaTypeNames.Application.Json)
                    });

                // Add a mocked HttpClient to IPaPdfApiService
                services.AddHttpClient<IPaPdfApiService, PaPdfApiService>()
                    .ConfigureHttpClient(client =>
                    {
                        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.10xhealthsystem.dev/");
                    })
                    .ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() => mockHttpHandler.Object);
            });
        });

        _client = _factory.CreateClient();
        // Register the mocked HttpClient with a name to ensure compatibility

    }

    [Fact]
    public async void Test_FillHealthHistoryQuestionnairePA_Ok()
    {

        // Arrange

        // Authenticate and get the JWT token
        var jwtToken = await _authModuleTests.GetAuthToken();

        // Add the token to the Authorization header
        _client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", jwtToken);

        var data = new HealthHistoryQuestionnaireData {
            AccountId = "3456789",
            PatientAgreementConfigurationId = "3456",
            PatientAgreementId = "2345",
            SignedDate = DateTime.Now,
        };
        var mockPatientInfo = new HealthHistoryQuestionnaire
        {
            PatientHeight = "5'10\"",
            PatientWeight = "170 lbs",
            PatientGender = "Male",
            PatientCellPhone = "123-456-7890"
            
        };

        data.Questionnaire = mockPatientInfo;


        var context = new StringContent(System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(data), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        // Act
        var response = await _client.PostAsync($"/api/personal-agreement/questionnaire/health-history", context);

        // Assert
        Assert.Equal(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK, response.StatusCode);

        var responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        var result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<ApiResponse<List<Account>>>(responseContent, new JsonSerializerOptions
        {
            PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true
        });
    }

When i debug the code view text explorer i see the inner SendAsync returned 400, bad request - because the real request is being called.
What is wrong in the above mocking that prevents this mock service from replacing the source request?

@IvanPetrov - you mean this :
services.AddHttpClient<IPaPdfApiService, PaPdfApiService>()
.ConfigureHttpClient(client =>
{
client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.10xhealthsystem.dev/");
})
.ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() => mockHttpHandler.Object);
});
});
    _client = _factory.CreateClient();
    // Register the mocked HttpClient with a name to ensure compatibility

}

or am i missing something ?

@IvanPetrov - i used  _client = _factory.CreateClient();
and then posted my request as
var response = await _client.PostAsync($"/api/personal-agreement/questionnaire/health-history", context);
i am new to integration test, is this wrong ?

looking at it again, it all makes sense.
